# MS Word 2011 for Mac: Can the header and footer be unlinked so I can have different numbering in each?

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, microsoft-word-2011, footers

I am working on a lengthy document. 
I need to have this **information in the HEADER**:

```
  Author, chapter #, page # OF THE CHAPTER
```

And **in the FOOTER**: *Consecutive* document page numbers

I have used section breaks effectively, so the headers work perfectly but, when I insert page number in the footer, linked to the previous section to get consecutive numbering throughout the document, the chapter (or section, if you will) numbering in the header changes to mimic the consecutive numbering of the footer.

Is there a way to "unlink" the different headers from a global footer?

Thank you in advance for any enlightenment you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Microsoft Office Word 2007 for Windows. 
I expect most recent versions of Microsoft Word will behave pretty much the same way,
except the shortcut keys may be different.  If the below doesn’t work,
check your Help documentation for instructions on how to create fields. 
You should be able to insert a page number by typing the word “page”
and then doing something. 
Once you figure out what that “something” is, you should be able to use it for the below.

Click at the beginning of your second section
(or at least somewhere on the first page of the second section)
and type “set sec2start page”. 
(“sec2start” is just an arbitrary name I have chosen – you can use something different
– but, as you might guess, “set” and “page” are keywords.) 
Select the word “page” and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. 
Curly braces will appear around the word “page”; as in “set sec2start **{** page **}**”. 
Now select the entire phrase and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> again. 
More curly braces will appear: “**{** set sec2start **{** page **}** **}**”. 
Now press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Now go into the header and type “= page - ref sec2start +1”. 
As before, select the word “page” and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. 
Then select “ref sec2start” and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. 
As before, curly braces will appear: “= **{** page **}** - **{** ref sec2start **}** +1”. 
Select this entire phrase and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> one more time. 
And press <kbd>F9</kbd> again.

Finally, press **<kbd>Alt</kbd>**+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

You should now have a magic number in the header of Section 2 that is the page number
within Section 2 – specifically, relative to the `sec2start` bookmark.

Repeat for each section.